# Font issue in TeX Live "Package fontspec Error: The font cannot be found."

Tags: fonts, miktex, fontspec, texlive

The following problem is appearing in `TeX Live`, not in `MiKTeX`.

The structure of my MWE project directory:

```
articles 
  - article1.tex
main.tex
style.sty
fontfilename.ttf       % For example: Patrick Hand.ttf (https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Patrick+Hand)
```

### article1.tex

```
% !TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{../style}
\begin{document}
\qtext{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.}
\end{document}
```

### main.tex

```
% !TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{style}
\begin{document}
\input{articles/article1}                           
\end{document}
```

### style.sty

```
\RequirePackage{docmute}
\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\quotefont{[fontfilename]} 
% \newfontfamily\quotefont{[Patrick Hand]}  % https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Patrick+Hand
\newcommand\qtext[1]{ \quotefont #1 }
```

The error "`Package fontspec Error: The font "[fontfilename]" cannot be found.`" is appearing when I compile the `article1.tex` with texlive. But the compilation of the `main.tex` doesn't give the error. On the other hand, no error shows up in miktex.

I have kept this MWE as a `Overleaf` project too. You can check it here: https://www.overleaf.com/read/twqghjmybnxm

What do I need to configure and fix so that my project's `article1.tex` and `main.tex` can be properly compiled both on miktex and texlive?

Comment: You shouldn't have brackets around `fontfilename`. You could try `\newfontfamily\quotefont{fontfilename.sty}`, and if that doesn't work, add `[Path=./]`.

Comment: @Davislor I just tried with `\newfontfamily\quotefont[Path=./]{Patrick Hand.ttf}` .
But my `article1.tex` is giving the same compilation error.

Comment: this  shouldn't work in miktex either, not if you start the compilation in the article folder. Add `\XeTeXtracingfonts=1`  to your article1.tex, compile with miktex and then show the log-file.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It worked in MiKTeX because the font was already installed? Here's the `main.log` (https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/MTGrrJJMMy/) and `article1.log` (https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/HfqcjPf2Hf/).

Comment: the article1.log shows that miktex gets the font from your user font folder: C:/Users/koutu/AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows/Fonts/Patrick Hand.ttf. Probably texlive can't find fonts there. Install it  in your system font instead (typically that means to install "as admin"). Or use luaotfload, there we added support for user font folders.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, I get it. Actually, I am using texlive on a different device (Ubuntu 20.04). Right now, I don't like to use the font by installing. I just want to keep my desired font file in the project directory and set up the font `Path` properly in `style.sty`. If I use `[Path=./]`, `article1.tex` can't find it and if `[Path=../]`, `main.tex` can't find it. How should I set it properly so that it can be used both on `main.tex` and `article1.tex`?

Comment: if you want a file, may it be your style.sty or a font file to be found from various other files in various locations then put it into the standard search path. This means either into a texmf-tree or in the case of fonts in the system font folder. Then you don't have to do convoluted things with Path and `../` syntax.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer is right. You can find your `TEXMFLOCAL` tree with `kpsewhich --var-value=TEXMFLOCAL`.  In some cases, you might want to use your `TEXMFHOME` tree instead. Then you can put it in a suitable subdirectory of that, such as `fonts/truetype/`.

Answer (score 1):

I am facing the similar issue, you can try to load fonts like this:

```
\setmainfont[
    Path = /your/font/path/,
  Extension = .otf ,
  BoldFont = HelveticaNeueLTPro-Md.otf ,
]{HelveticaNeueLTPro-Roman.otf}
```